# pptp VPN over WiFi doesn't work

Tags: wireless, 14.04, vpn, ethernet, pptp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to set up a **pptp VPN** between me and a server. I am using `network-manager` for this.

Now, the VPN works perfectly when I'm on **Ethernet**, whereas on **WiFi** my laptop doesn't know how to reach the server (even though `ping` works as exepected):

```
15:50:35  NetworkManager[16692]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
15:50:35  NetworkManager[16692]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 28057
15:50:35  NetworkManager[16692]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
15:50:35  NetworkManager[16692]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]: <info> VPN connection 'pacage' (Connect) reply received.
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Using interface ppp0
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/23
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
15:50:40  pptp[28073]: nm-pptp-service-28057 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
15:50:40  pptp[28075]: nm-pptp-service-28057 warn[open_inetsock:pptp_callmgr.c:329]: connect: No route to host
15:50:40  pptp[28075]: nm-pptp-service-28057 fatal[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:127]: Could not open control connection to x.x.x.x
15:50:40  pptp[28073]: nm-pptp-service-28057 fatal[open_callmgr:pptp.c:487]: Call manager exited with error 256
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Modem hangup
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Connection terminated.
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
15:50:40  NetworkManager[16692]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
15:50:40  pppd[28069]: Exit.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: PPTP is neither TCP nor UDP, but another protocol called GRE. May be your router blocks it?

Comment: Yeah, after a bit of googling, I don't see any other possible reason. I'll try from a different wifi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may simply be that the GRE packets are not getting through.

To resolve this issue, make sure the Wifi router or firewall permits GRE protocol 47 (You will want to find and enable a "PPTP passthrough" feature on your router that knows how to handle the GRE packets). In fact both port 1723 and GRE protocol shoyld be opened/enabled to establish VPN connectivity by using PPTP.

Hope it could solve the problem.